# Python: using a recursive algorithm as a generator

Tags: python, recursion, generator

Recently I wrote a function to generate certain sequences with nontrivial constraints. The problem came with a natural recursive solution. Now it happens that, even for relatively small input, the sequences are several thousands, thus I would prefer to use my algorithm as a generator instead of using it to fill a list with all the sequences.

Here is an example. Suppose we want to compute all the permutations of a string with a recursive function. The following naive algorithm takes an extra argument 'storage' and appends a permutation to it whenever it finds one:

```
def getPermutations(string, storage, prefix=""):
   if len(string) == 1:
      storage.append(prefix + string)   # <-----
   else:
      for i in range(len(string)):
         getPermutations(string[:i]+string[i+1:], storage, prefix+string[i])

storage = []
getPermutations("abcd", storage)
for permutation in storage: print permutation
```

(Please don't care about inefficiency, this is only an example.)

Now I want to turn my function into a generator, i.e. to yield a permutation instead of appending it to the storage list:

```
def getPermutations(string, prefix=""):
   if len(string) == 1:
      yield prefix + string             # <-----
   else:
      for i in range(len(string)):
         getPermutations(string[:i]+string[i+1:], prefix+string[i])

for permutation in getPermutations("abcd"):
   print permutation
```

This code does *not* work (the function behaves like an empty generator).

Am I missing something?
Is there a way to turn the above recursive algorithm into a generator *without replacing it with an iterative one*?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
def getPermutations(string, prefix=""):
    if len(string) == 1:
        yield prefix + string
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(string)):
            for perm in getPermutations(string[:i] + string[i+1:], prefix+string[i]):
                yield perm
```

Or without an accumulator:

```
def getPermutations(string):
    if len(string) == 1:
        yield string
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(string)):
            for perm in getPermutations(string[:i] + string[i+1:]):
                yield string[i] + perm
```

Comment: In Python 3.4, you can replace the last two lines with `yield from getPermutations(string[:i] + string[i+1:])`, which is more efficient in many ways!

Comment: You would still need to build the result in some way. Using `yield from` would require you to use the accumulator argument (`prefix`).

Comment: Suggestion: Define another generator that returns `string[i],string[:i]+string[i+1:]` pairs. Then it would be: `for letter,rest in first_letter_options(string): for perm in getPermuations(rest): yield letter+perm`

Answer (score 29):

This avoids the `len(string)`-deep recursion, and is in general a nice way to handle generators-inside-generators:

```
from types import GeneratorType

def flatten(*stack):
    stack = list(stack)
    while stack:
        try: x = stack[0].next()
        except StopIteration:
            stack.pop(0)
            continue
        if isinstance(x, GeneratorType): stack.insert(0, x)
        else: yield x

def _getPermutations(string, prefix=""):
    if len(string) == 1: yield prefix + string
    else: yield (_getPermutations(string[:i]+string[i+1:], prefix+string[i])
            for i in range(len(string)))

def getPermutations(string): return flatten(_getPermutations(string))

for permutation in getPermutations("abcd"): print permutation
```

`flatten` allows us to continue progress in another generator by simply `yield`ing it, instead of iterating through it and `yield`ing each item manually.

---

Python 3.3 will add [`yield from`](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator) to the syntax, which allows for natural delegation to a sub-generator:

```
def getPermutations(string, prefix=""):
    if len(string) == 1:
        yield prefix + string
    else:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            yield from getPermutations(string[:i]+string[i+1:], prefix+string[i])
```

Answer (score 20):

The interior call to getPermutations -- it's a generator, too.

```
def getPermutations(string, prefix=""):
   if len(string) == 1:
      yield prefix + string            
   else:
      for i in range(len(string)):
         getPermutations(string[:i]+string[i+1:], prefix+string[i])  # <-----
```

You need to iterate through that with a for-loop (see @MizardX posting, which edged me out by seconds!)