# Yield with recursion in python

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to generate a Set product of two string using generator approach than storing it in a list as follows:

```
def recursive_generator(l_set, index = 0, value = ""):
    if index == len(l_set):
        yield(value)
    else:
        for i in l_set[index]:
            recursive_generator(l_set, index + 1, value + i)

def main():
    _input = ["ab","de"]
    for i in recursive_generator(_input):
        print(i)

main()
```

The expected outcome is `ad ae bd be` new line seperated but on execution, there is no result.
On checking with pdb to see the behaviour:

```
$ python3 -m pdb recurse.py 
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(1)<module>()
-> def recursive_generator(l_set, index = 0, value = ""):
(Pdb) n
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(8)<module>()
-> def main():
(Pdb) n
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(13)<module>()
-> main()
(Pdb) step
--Call--
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(8)main()
-> def main():
(Pdb) n
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(9)main()
-> _input = ["ab","de"]
(Pdb) n
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(10)main()
-> for i in recursive_generator(_input):
(Pdb) step
--Call--
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(1)recursive_generator()
-> def recursive_generator(l_set, index = 0, value = ""):
(Pdb) locals()
{'l_set': ['ab', 'de'], 'index': 0, 'value': ''}
(Pdb) n
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(2)recursive_generator()
-> if index == len(l_set):
(Pdb) len(l_set)
2
(Pdb) n
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(5)recursive_generator()
-> for i in l_set[index]:
(Pdb) n
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(6)recursive_generator()
-> recursive_generator(l_set, index + 1, value + i)
(Pdb) step
--Call--
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(1)recursive_generator()
-> def recursive_generator(l_set, index = 0, value = ""):
(Pdb) locals()
{'l_set': ['ab', 'de'], 'index': 1, 'value': 'a'}
(Pdb) n
GeneratorExit   <<<<< It did not proceed for the next loop, did not even check the if condition


> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(1)recursive_generator()
-> def recursive_generator(l_set, index = 0, value = ""):
(Pdb) w
  /usr/lib64/python3.7/bdb.py(578)run()
-> exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  <string>(1)<module>()
  /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(13)<module>()
-> main()
  /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(10)main()
-> for i in recursive_generator(_input):
  /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(6)recursive_generator()
-> recursive_generator(l_set, index + 1, value + i)
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(1)recursive_generator()
-> def recursive_generator(l_set, index = 0, value = ""):
(Pdb) n
Internal StopIteration
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(10)main()
-> for i in recursive_generator(_input):
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(10)main()->None
-> for i in recursive_generator(_input):
(Pdb) w
  /usr/lib64/python3.7/bdb.py(578)run()
-> exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  <string>(1)<module>()
  /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(13)<module>()
-> main()
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(10)main()->None
-> for i in recursive_generator(_input):
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(13)<module>()->None
-> main()
(Pdb) w
  /usr/lib64/python3.7/bdb.py(578)run()
-> exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  <string>(1)<module>()->None
> /home/ec2-user/recurse.py(13)<module>()->None
-> main()
```

I am not able to understand the flow break here on why it will perform a generator exit and stops the iteration. Is this approach supported ? I am a noob when comes to python and am learning generators and iterators. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think your recursive generator function is quite right, You can look at [Can generators be recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254304/can-generators-be-recursive), You need to use `yield from <gen func name>` for recursive behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is just calling `recursive_generator` in the loop but not `yielding` any values (similar to returning a value in a non-generator recursive function where you just return the recursive function call). You need to use `yield from` inside the loop to get the recursive behavior of the generator function.

```py
def recursive_generator(l_set, index = 0, value = ""):
    if index == len(l_set):
        yield(value)
    else:
        for i in l_set[index]:
            yield from recursive_generator(l_set, index + 1, value + i)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
ad
ae
bd
be
```