# Dictionary leaf generator

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, tree

Here it is my tree, a nested dictionary

```
tree = {"root": {"branch_a": {"branch_aa": 0, "branch_ab": 1},
                 "branch_b": 1,
                 "branch_c": {"branch_ca": {"branch_caa": 0}}}}
```

I managed to write a function that prints all the leaves

```
def print_leaves(tree):
    if not hasattr(tree, "__iter__"):
        print(tree)
    elif isinstance(tree, dict):
        for branch in tree.values():
            print_leaves(branch)
```

which produces the desired output

```
0
1
1
0
```

At this point I thought it would have been nice to decouple the action (printing in this case) from the access to the leaves. So I modified the function above slightly, turned it into a generator and moved the printing part in a for loop.

```
def generate_leaves(tree):
    if not hasattr(tree, "__iter__"):
        yield tree
    elif isinstance(tree, dict):
        for branch in tree.values():
            generate_leaves(branch)

for leaf in generate_leaves(tree):
    print(leaf)
```

... which unfortunately doesn't work.

First of all why, doesn't it work?
And then, of course, how to properly write a leaf generator?

Comment: Your second example mixes the two function names `print_leaves` and `generate_leaves`, is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Nope, corrected now thx

Comment: Also I suggest replacing your `if / elif` which has two redundant conditions, with a `if / else` with only one condition. For instance, `if not isinstance(tree, dict): ... else: ...`

Comment: So now you've edited the question to correct a mistake in the code. Does the code still not work?

Comment: Actually, the recursive call is wrong. You're calling `generate_leaves(branch)` but not using the result. That worked for `print_leaves` because it was not returning a result, just printing to screen. A simple way to use the result of a generator is to use the `yield from` syntax: `yield from generate_leaves(branch)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the result of the recursive call. That worked for `print_leaves` which didn't have a return value, but that doesn't work for a function with `return` or `yield`.

Here is the long version:

```py
def generate_leaves(tree):
    if not hasattr(tree, "__iter__"):
        yield tree
    elif isinstance(tree, dict):
        for branch in tree.values():
            for leaf in generate_leaves(branch):
                yield leaf

for leaf in generate_leaves(tree):
    print(leaf)
```

Fortunately, we can make that a lot shorter with `yield from`:

```py
def generate_leaves(tree):
    if not hasattr(tree, "__iter__"):
        yield tree
    elif isinstance(tree, dict):
        for branch in tree.values():
            yield from generate_leaves(branch)

for leaf in generate_leaves(tree):
    print(leaf)
```

Note that you only need an `if / else` with one condition; no need for an `if / elif` with two redundant conditions:

```py
def generate_leaves(tree):
    if not isinstance(tree, dict):
        yield tree
    else:
        for branch in tree.values():
            yield from generate_leaves(branch)

for leaf in generate_leaves(tree):
    print(leaf)
```

Resources about `yield from`:

- [PEP-0380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/);
- [In practice, what are the main uses for the new "yield from" syntax in Python 3.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3)
- [Can generators be recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254304/can-generators-be-recursive)